# How to use multiple variables in PQexecParams() in C

Tags: c, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to create a client / server application, however I've come across an issue in the server application. I want the server app to accept a structure containing multiple variables from the client app, and then use these variable values inside an "INSERT INTO" psql statement. However, as the title suggests, I'm having an issue with how I could code this. Below, you will find the relevant parts of my code:

```
struct PersonInfo* buffer = (struct PersonInfo*)malloc(sizeof(struct  
PersonInfo));

recv(serv_sock_accept, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

//**Connection to database using PGconn (PGconn connection)**

PGresult* res = PQexecParams(connection, 
               "INSERT INTO person(first_name, last_name, age) VALUES($1, $2, $3)",
               3,
               NULL,
               buffer->person.fname, buffer->person.lname, buffer->age,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               0);
```

I keep getting compile errors on the line where I declare my variable values, which is leading me to believe that I can't declare multiple values on this line of the PQexecParams() function. I feel that my way is wrong, thus could you guys please point me in the right direction? Is it possible to declare multiple values on the Value line in one PQexecParams() statement? If I break up the three values into their own PQexecParams() statement, the database will create three separate entries, as opposed to just one.

Thank you so much for all the help that you guys have provided to me thus far!

Answer (score 4):

It can be done, but not in the way you are trying to do it. The PostgreSQL documentation defines the signature for that function as

```
PGresult *PQexecParams(PGconn *conn,
                       const char *command,
                       int nParams,
                       const Oid *paramTypes,
                       const char * const *paramValues,
                       const int *paramLengths,
                       const int *paramFormats,
                       int resultFormat);
```

You can't just add extra arguments into the function call and expect it to understand you; that's not how C works. However, if we look at that signature, we see that the values are passed as

```
const char * const *paramValues,
```

If we pretend we can't see the `const` keyword, this is a `char**` which can be passed in as an array of `char*`s.

Try creating the array as shown below, then passing it in where you have tried to pass in your multiple fields.

```
char* values[3];
values[0] = buffer->person.fname;
values[1] = buffer->person.lname;
values[2] = buffer->person.age;
```

**Note** - this code makes the assumption that all three fields are char*, which I realise is a pretty big assumption for 'age'. If it is an `int` you will either have to work out how to convert it to a string, or how to use the binary mode provided by that function. I think that is beyond the scope of this question however.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your input, I really appreciate it. I tried doing what you mentioned, but if I declare values as "char* values[3]", I get a compiler warning stating "passing argument 5 of 'PQexecParams' from incompatible pointer type, values". However, if I declare values as "const char* values[3]", I receive no compiler warnings, and it compiles just fine. But when I call the server from my client app, the psql statement does not execute. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the whole error line, usually incompatible pointer errors tell you what it is expecting and what it got

Comment: "note: expected 'const char * const*' but argument is of type 'char **' extern PGresult *PQexecParams(PGconn *conn)